# Is there any difference how many $(document).ready() I have?

Tags: jquery

I understand jQuery, I just wanna ask, whats the difference between those 2 code examples (I know, it will do the same, but I am curious, if there is something specific with second example.

**EXAMPLE 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // some code #1
    // some code #2
    // some code #3
});
```

Here is all JS at one place.

**EXAMPLE 2:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // some code #1
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // some code #2
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // some code #3
});
```

Those functions (DOM ready) are placed in different JS files.

I am just thinking, how it will be processed, but I guess it will be executed after DOM is loaded and then in the order, how it is called in HTML.

Comment: youre guess is correct

Comment: As a personal choice, I wouldn't split the code across many places. This just makes it harder to have a full picture of what's going on.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: yes, thats true, but sometimes you need to generate dynamic JS code for `$(document).ready()`, and you have it inline in your HTML code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK. Makes it easier to add/remove components though..

Comment: What I meant is to put everything within a single document ready handler, in a separated JS file. Not to write down everything inline. But this is just a personal choice, and of course there are situations where you can't just do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each separate function passed to `$(document).ready()` will create its own scope for variables and functions, which can result in a pretty substantial difference. Take these two examples:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function viewEvent(event) {
        console.log(event);
        return false;
    }

    $('a').on('click', viewEvent);
    // works fine, clicking on an <a> element will log the event object
});
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function viewEvent(event) {
        console.log(event);
        return false;
    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', viewEvent);
    // won't work, viewEvent is out of scope here
});
```

Comment: This is what I was asking for :)

Comment: having multiple scopes is often a benefit. Perhaps a better example would be where `viewEvent` is defined twice?

Answer (score 3):

Multiple document ready handlers will all be called in the order they are bound. In general I would recommend just having the one to keep things tidy, except...

> *"Those functions (DOM ready) are places in different JS files."*

That is the best reason I can think of for having multiple ready handlers.

> *"I am just thinking, how it will be processed, but I guess it will be executed after DOM is loaded and then in the order, how it is called in HTML."*

That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many of them as you wish, and they will be executed in the order that the `$()` or `$(document).ready()` functions are executed. (i.e. each handler is added to the queue).

Comment: I think you'll start running out of memory somewhere around 10 million, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak - That's OK, I start running out of patience around 9.5 million.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess it will be executed after DOM is loaded and then in the order, how it is called in HTML.

That's correct.

These functions will be stacked and called linear in the order they are attached to the DOM ready event.